# how to store data from a pdf file to sqlite for using in iPhone programmimng

Tags: iphone, sqlite, pdf

I am having a pdf file contaning quotes of some famous people.I want to store these quotes in sqlite database.any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct relation with pdf and sqlite.

First you have to somehow decode the information/data from pdf file. Read the quotes in text format.

Then you can insert them in a sqlite database.

Its a kind of tough job to decode information from pdf file. Then you need to know the structure of the pdf file format. You can get a description here [pdf file format](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html)

I think you can look for some pdf file converter to convert it into text, html, xml or csv. Then read that by your app.

Comment: yes i have to decode the information but that is my problem..i dont want to decode manually

Answer (score 0):

I think best way is through command line

awk '{printf"INSERT INTO Quotes VALUES (\x27%s\x27,\x27 Abraham Lincon\x27);\n",$0}' Quotes-AbrahamLincon.txt

where Quotes-AbrahamLincon.txt contains

A friend is one who has the same enemies as you have.

A house divided against itself cannot stand.

A woman is the only thing I am afraid of that I know will not hurt me.

output will be

INSERT INTO Quotes VALUES ('A friend is one who has the same enemies as you have.',' Abraham Lincon');

INSERT INTO Quotes VALUES ('A house divided against itself cannot stand.',' Abraham Lincon');

INSERT INTO Quotes VALUES ('A woman is the only thing I am afraid of that I know will not hurt me.',' Abraham Lincon');

now you can write this into sqlite db

Comment: dude never thought that this was so simple!...but what is the command if I  want only the quote('A house divided against itself cannot stand.')..tried for some time but couldn't solve